# Как GtkFileChooser указать путь к файлу?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Как `GtkFileChooser` указать путь к файлу? Допустим, у меня есть путь `file:///home/mrdoctorwho/some.png`, мне надо указать этот путь кнопке `gtkFileChooserButton`, чтобы потом его же получить по `filechooser.get_file()`.

Answer (score 1):

Для установки предлагаемого имени файла, используйте метод:

```
chooser.set_current_name(name)
```

[отсюда](http://pygtk.ru/pygtk2tutorial/sec-FileChoosers.html)

Comment: Это не то, чего я хотел. Допустим, у меня есть путь file:///home/mrdoctorwho/some.png, мне надо указать этот путь кнопке gtkFileChooserButton, чтобы потом его же получить по filechooser.get_file()